# Runtime Error 2147024809 (80070057): Could not find the specified object

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I recently ran into an issue with my project that is really throwing me for a loop.  My project is no longer recognizing 2 of my 11 forms that have been in existence virtually since the program's inception. The names of the forms have not changed, nor has the code calling the forms changed.  These 2 forms were being called previously without an issue and now this runtime error exists.  The two forms not coming up anymore are "Vacation_Days_Form" and "Vacation_Holidays_Form", as the code below explains.  Another issue is the "Holidays_Form" userform, which is being called but no data is actually being outputted to the program.  Again, this form was previously working fine and now is not after no code pertaining to the form was changed.  The only one of the main forms that works from the code below is "Normal_Iteration", which is embedded in Module1 (not a userform).  Below is my code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Options
        .AddItem "No Vacation or Holidays"
        .AddItem "Vacation"
        .AddItem "Holiday"
        .AddItem "Vacation & Holidays"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Vacation_Options_Select_Click()
    Vacation_Options_Form.Hide
    Dim List_Options As Integer
    For List_Options = 0 To Options.ListCount - 1
        If Options.Selected(List_Options) = True Then
            If Options.List(List_Options) = "No Vacation or Holidays" Then
                Call Normal_Iteration
            ElseIf Options.List(List_Options) = "Vacation" Then
                Vacation_Days_Form.Show
            ElseIf Options.List(List_Options) = "Holiday" Then
                Holidays_Form.Show
            ElseIf Options.List(List_Options) = "Vacation & Holidays" Then
                Vacation_Holidays_Form.Show
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

To answer these questions ahead of time: 1) yes, I have checked to see these userforms still exist in my program; and 2) yes, the userforms are named exactly as they are called out in the code above.

Thanks for your help in detecting the issue.  Please let me know if there is additional code necessary for me to post.

Regards,

Jordan

Comment: VBA projects can occasionally become corrupted - I would try Rob Bovey's Code Cleaner and see if that fixes the problem. http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just redoing my project, essentially copying my code, forms, formatting, etc. to another workbook, starting from scratch.  I still have no idea exactly what happened.  MS Office 2007 appears to have significant reliability issues.  Thanks for your help.